# Django webpage giving 404 error when I write the code to give video forward option

Tags: python, django, wsgi

I am using django to make a website that shows some movies for me to watch when I am not at home.
The code was working well, with the website showing the movie, letting me play it and everything that I wanted, except that i can't go forward and back in the movie. I spent a lot of time trying to solve that problem and I found some videos that explained how to make that work.
But, when I write the code, django works normally, but if I try to access the website it shows me a 404 error, just saying "404 Not Found", without the usual 404 error page that django have.
The code that is making all of this is `application = Ranges(Cling(MediaCling(get_wsgi_application())))` in the wsgi.py file.
Everything works fine until I add the MediaCling part.
I have installed the libraries and writed the code equal to the videos that I watch.
What I am doing wrong?

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

from dj_static import Cling, MediaCling
from static_ranges import Ranges

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Movies_site.settings')

application = Ranges(Cling(MediaCling(get_wsgi_application())))
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you're sticking with dj_static? It's [deprecated since 2017](https://github.com/heroku-python/dj-static), it's recommended to migrate to [Whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/)

Comment: It was the library that was used in the videos that I watched and in the sites.
Thank you for telling me about Whitenoise. I've done a deeper search about that library and I was able to solve the problem. Thank you!